# Automate Reading the SMS Pin with Twitter Digits IOS

Tags: ios, twitter-digits

I already know how to do it for Android : https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#automate-reading-the-sms-pin

I am looking fot the same thing for IOS. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Text messages in iOS cannot be accessed by other applications.

Comment: I saw it working on the Lyft app though. So there must be a way

Comment: @Hyacinthe not on iOS you didnt. I just tried installing lyft on iOS 10 and it couldnt read my sms code. Duskwuff is correct

Comment: You're right. That's weird I remembered using an app that did it on IOS but don't remember which one. Anyway thanks a lot guys for your help :)